# how to get returned value from stored function in PDO?

Tags: php, oracle, function, pdo

I have this code :

```
include("connect.php");
// Call database function
$p = 100;
$sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT ISPPRO.USERPKG.GET_USER(:bind1, :bind3) AS v FROM DUAL');
$sth->bindParam(":bind1", $p, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(":bind3", $p, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r( $result);
echo "<br><pre>";
print_r($conn->errorInfo());
echo "</pre>";
```

The `ISPPRO.USERPKG.GET_USER` returns 1 or 0;

How I can get it??

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I changed the above code and I am getting this error:

```
OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00904: "ISPPRO"."USERPKG"."GET_USER": invalid identifier
```

Comment: You don't say what your DBMS is but, in general terms, procedures are supposed to *not* return values. Perhaps you have to write a function instead :-?

Comment: Can you show me how to get returned value from function?

Comment: In MySQL you'd do a regular `SELECT my_function() AS name` query and read the value from `name`. You don't say what your DBMS is.

Comment: I am using PDO_Oracle not MYSQL, what should I do?

Comment: I've *assumed* that `GET_USER()` is a function and added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have execute permission on the package?

User ISPPRO should run the command

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON userpkg TO <your_user>;
```

An easy way to check if you've been granted execute on this package is to run this command:

```
SELECT privilege
  FROM all_tab_privs
 WHERE table_schema = 'ISPPRO'
   AND table_name = 'USERPKG';
```

You should get a row with EXECUTE as the privilege.

Comment: well, I don't know because I am not the DBA, I get my connect information and some function from DBA to apply it in a website but I guess he did it

Comment: I'd ask. It's an easy thing to forget, and if you don't do it, this is exactly the error message you get.

Comment: When I run the last query, I get this error `OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00911: invalid character`, WHY??

Comment: I've edited the answer, perhaps it does not like '*'. I intended that query to be run via SQL*Plus. Just select the privilege column.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Oracle function that returns a scalar you read it as any other value, e.g.:

```
SELECT ISPPRO.USERPKG.GET_USER(:user, :pass) AS foo
FROM DUAL
```

... and read the value from the column `foo` as in any other query.

Comment: I edited the question and now I am getting this error : `OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00904: "ISPPRO"."USERPKG"."GET_USER": invalid identifier`